# Xamarin forms FormattedText on buttons

Tags: xamarin.forms

The UI object `Xamarin.Forms.Label`  object supports the property `FormattedText`.
Unfortunately there is only a simple property `Text` on the UI object `Xamarin.Forms.Buttons`.
Is there a way to have a button appear with formatted text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without creating a custom renderer.

Comment: possible option is to use a frame instead of a button (may be useful for some readers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926894/i-need-to-have-formatted-text-inside-a-xamarin-forms-button-two-different-sizes

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the string in the ViewModel and Bind to the Button Text Property;