# I need to have formatted text inside a Xamarin Forms button (two different sizes)

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project, and I need to have a custom button.  The button would look something like this:

[image]

I assume I need to create a custom renderer, but I can't figure out how to have two different font sizes inside a button?

I need renderers for both Android and iOS.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

How about skipping the custom renderer and use a `Frame` w/ a tap gesture that encloses a formatted text `Label`:

```
<Frame VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="Gray" BorderColor="Black">
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnFrameTapped"/>
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    <Label>
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                <Span Text="2" FontSize="30" />
                <Span Text="ABC" FontSize="15" />
            </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
</Frame>
```

[image]